# Assign clipboard object in mathematica when print screen is pressed (windows)

Tags: programming, clipboard

Mathematica runs behind, while another window is selected. When I press print screen, I want mathematica too detect this and call a function with the picture as argument.

```
Paste[];
Image[%[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]]
```

Returns the screenshot, but I need it to be one command and picture shouldnt be almost destroyed as it happens with the command above. How should I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
Binarize /@  ToExpression@ Cases[NotebookGet[ClipboardNotebook[]], BoxData[_], Infinity]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]